# RealmMigrationNeededException in C# adding only one property

Tags: c#, xamarin, migration, realm

I have an app that uses Realm db. I have added a string property to UserRealm named Test.

When I try to run my app it writes

> Realms.Exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required
>   due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'UserRealm .Test' has been added.

I'm trying to search on the internet, but almost everywhere the solution is deleting the old database. I dont want to delete the old database, I need to keep it and just add this one column.

This is a Xamarin/C# project.

How can I just simply add a sinle property migration to the realm? It's no problem if the default value is string.Empty.

I Use 
Realm nuget 3.4.0,
Realm.Database 3.4.0
Fody 3.3.4

Answer (score -1):

Just add a `MigrationCallback` to your `RealmConfiguration`, you do not have to do anything within that callback if no data transformation is needed and you do not need to init new properties to something other than their default values in Realm.

```
var config = new RealmConfiguration
{
    SchemaVersion = 2,
    MigrationCallback = (migration, oldSchemaVersion) =>
    {
    }
};
```

re: https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest#performing-a-migration

Comment: @tixovoxi Is the callback being triggered?